# In Spring mvc, when i am hitting the CURL then getting error in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, curl

i have a curl type of url,

> `curl -i -X GET -H Accept:application/json http://localhost:8080/onyxcxm/admin/getDTMF/2`

when i hitting the url and get Responce like,

> HTTP/1.1 302
>
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>
> X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0,
>
> must-revalidate Pragma: no-cache
>
> Expires: 0 X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>
> Location: http://localhost:8080/onyxcxm/login
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> Date: Thu, 04 Oct 2018 11:36:48 GMT

and here my controller like,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getDTMF/{dtmf}",headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getDTMF(@PathVariable("dtmf") String dtmf) {
    System.err.println("Pressed digit is "+dtmf);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(null, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

and my security configuration is,

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .headers().addHeaderWriter(
            new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(
            XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter.XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN))
            .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
    .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())
    .failureUrl("/login?error")
    .usernameParameter("username")
    .passwordParameter("password")
    .and()
    .logout()
    .logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")
    .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler())
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
    .and()
    .csrf().disable();
}
```

> i don't think why i get this error, can any one solve it ? Thanks.

Comment: Because you aren't authenticated. You get redirected to the login page.

Comment: so how to i authenticate it here and thanks to quick reply.

Comment: Enable basic authentication and send basic auth headers with curl... Or disable security.

Comment: but dear, how to i enable Basic auth also when i have alredy encrypted password by  BCryptPasswordEncoder. if you have any example can you share with me. thanks

Comment: `http.httpBasic().and().<what you had>`. Something like that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you are experiencing is by your own design. You are requesting a page under path '/admin/**', which requires authentication according to the security configuration you have setup.

So this is what Spring is doing:

- Check if you have a valid authentication token
- If present allow call to be passed to the @Controller and @RequestMapping
- If not redirect to the configured login page (in your case "/login")

Since you are not providing any security token (which can be obtained by a login on the /login page and should be passed in the headers) Spring redirects the CURL request to the login page configured. A status code 302 means just that, redirect the user to the specified page.

For basic authentication add a header 'Authorization: userHash', where you replace the userHash with an base64-encoded string of <username>:<password>. See wikipedia [Basic Access Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) for more information on how to use the header.

Comment: Can you provide any Example, i have  BCryptPasswordEncoder password here.

Comment: Basic auth has nothing to do with the BCryptEncoder. It is an base64 encoded hash of the username and password combined into the Authentication header.